# I would like to store prefabs after they are instantiated in an array

Tags: unity-game-engine

I made a GameManager script where I want to store all the prefabs which are instantiated in an array.

```
    public static GameManager instance;
    public bool isCheck;

    public GameObject[] props;
```

OtherScript

```
        Ray mouseRay = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        if (Physics.Raycast(mouseRay.origin, mouseRay.direction, out hit, 1000f, ~groundLayer))
        {
            GameManager.instance.props = Instantiate(prefab, hit.point + Vector3.up * .5f, Quaternion.identity);
            gameObject.SetActive(false);

            return;
        }

        transform.position = startPosition;
    }
}
```

Comment: You cannot access `props` this way, it is an `array`, not a single `GameObject` and it is not initialized. Besides that: What exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: For now, I want to just save the prefabs which have been instantiated in an array.

Comment: then of course you can store them in an array spawned_stuff[i] = instantiate....

Answer (score 0):

1. Use a list instead of an array to have variable length, initialize the list:

```
public List<GameObject> props = new List<GameObject>();
```

2. Add the entries to the list after instantiation:

```
var newProp = Instantiate(prefab, hit.point + Vector3.up * .5f, Quaternion.identity);
GameManager.instance.props.Add(newProp);
```

Comment: My pleasure. Please accept the answer if it helped you and upvote if you can. :)

Comment: Ideally, your `GameManager` instance should have a method that adds the prop to it - to avoid breaking encapsulation: `GameManager.instance.AddProp(newProp)`.